# primefaces menubar logout right side

Tags: jsf, primefaces, alignment, menubar

Hi I followed this code but my logout button is not at the right side of menubar.

[sample from PF](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/menubar.jsf)

here is my xhtml page

```
<h:body>
    <p:menubar autoDisplay="false">
        <p:menuitem value="Home" url="/index.jsf" />

        <p:submenu label="Maintenance" >
            <p:menuitem value="Course" url="/views/course/list.jsf" />
            <p:menuitem value="Student" url="/index.jsf" />
        </p:submenu>

        <f:facet name="options">
            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Logout" icon="ui-icon-extlink" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:menubar>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Which version of primefaces are you using. According to the blog: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2347 This would be a feature of the not yet final 3.5 release

Comment: Once you upgrade your PrimeFaces to 3.5, then you need redeploy and clear browser cache (hard refresh).

Answer (score 4):

You should use a style="float: right;" inside the button or include the property into your css stylesheet.

Comment: It only works when I remove it from menubar, it kills the purpose of menubar.

Comment: It works for me. I'm wondering how much tricky is this solution, that is if it is guaranteed to work in different contions and browsers. btw, i'm using pf 3.2

Comment: Then the menù itself goes beyond the edge of the browser window because it is alligned with the starting of the item in the menù bar. I've adjusted this in a rather tricky way this way: style="float:right;margin-right: 30px;"

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get the logout to the right by using the below code

```
<f:facet name="options">
   <p:commandButton type="button" value="Logout" />
</f:facet>
```

Comment: yes, I already fixed it by updating my primefaces jar file to 3.5, no code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use: **inputText style="margin-right:10px"** in the facet... Surely will work.

Answer (score 0):

It will work only in primefaces 3.5 change to primefaces 3.5 and it will work you can verify this at primefaces link [primefaces blog](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2347%5B1%5D)

For more details go to primefaces showcase page [primefaces showcase menubar sample page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf)    for sample code this code is from that sample page

`<f:facet name="options">

            <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px"/>

            <p:commandButton type="button" value="Logout" icon="ui-icon-extlink" />

    </f:facet>`

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

if your using prime-faces 5, then it should work. Try to browse your application in a web browser instead of the IDE your using to code. Because It's not appear as we expected in the IDE but it's work fine in a web browser. You can also use styleClass inside the  tag. insert styleClass="margin-riight:10px" inside the button tag